# return function within if statement not executing

Tags: javascript, string

Hey so i'm writing a function that checks whether a series of braces is a valid sequence. I have the following code, which mostly does what I want it to do, except it it always returns false. If i enter a valid sequence of braces it ends up in the right if-statement, but never returns true. I don't understand why.

```js
function match(s) {
  if (s === '(') {
    return ')'
  }
  else if (s === '[') {
    return ']'
  }
  else if (s === '{') {
    return '}'
  }
}

function open(b) {
  if ( (b === '(' ) || (b === '[' ) || (b === '{') ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function checkValid(string, temp, n) {
  var current = string.charAt(n)
  var currentMatch = temp.charAt(0)

  if (!(current) && (n === string.length) && (temp === "")) {
    console.log('hey')
    return true
  }

  if (open(current)) {
    temp = match(current).concat(temp)
    checkValid(string, temp, n+1)
  }
  else {
    if (current === currentMatch) {
      temp = temp.substr(1)
      checkValid(string, temp, n+1)
    }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

function validBraces(braces) {
  var n = 0
  var temp = ''
  return checkValid(braces, temp, n)
}

validBraces('()') // should return true
validBraces('[[)}}{') //should return false
```

Answer (score 0):

The last return false is always being returned from your original checkValid function call.

This is because you aren't returning the recursive checkValid calls.

```js
function match(s) {
  if (s === '(') {
    return ')'
  }
  else if (s === '[') {
    return ']'
  }
  else if (s === '{') {
    return '}'
  }
}

function open(b) {
  if ( (b === '(' ) || (b === '[' ) || (b === '{') ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function checkValid(string, temp, n) {
  var current = string.charAt(n)
  var currentMatch = temp.charAt(0)

  if (!(current) && (n === string.length) && (temp === "")) {
    console.log('hey')
    return true
  }

  if (open(current)) {
    temp = match(current).concat(temp)
    return checkValid(string, temp, n+1)
  }
  else {
    if (current === currentMatch) {
      temp = temp.substr(1)
      return checkValid(string, temp, n+1)
    }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

function validBraces(braces) {
  var n = 0
  var temp = ''
  return checkValid(braces, temp, n)
}

validBraces('()') // should return true
validBraces('[[)}}{') //should return false
```

Comment: gee whiz. time to go to bed i suppose.. Thanks!